# How can my Rails app accept RAILS_GEM_VERSION minor version bumps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, environment

My rails project has this line in /config/environment.rb

```
# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

As we now have 2.3.5 as the most recent upgrade, is there a way to make my environment.rb accept minor version bumps?

(without I have to explicitly change 2.3.2 to 2.3.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You application needs to use a specific Rails version mostly because different tiny releases might require additional steps to upgrade the framework such as changes to boot.rb.

```
$ rake rails:update
```

Answer (score 1):

Things have evolved a bit since Rails 2, so Ill share what I had to do to get from 5.0.0 to 5.0.0.1 today.

My `Gemfile` read `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'`. I figured that was [enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101591/what-does-mean-in-a-gem-file), but `bundle install` was not updating anything new. So I tried to force it with  `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0'` which also did nothing new when I ran update (note: this is for an experimental app of my own, and not someone else's app I am working on - don't just default to allowing minor version updates to solve problems like this ;) ). So I had to try a few other ways to force this security patch/hotfix.

First, I had to install the package locally:

`gem install rails --version 5.0.0.1`

Next, I updated bundler:

`bundle install`

...and I saw this in the output: `Using rails 5.0.0.1 (was 5.0.0)`

---

When I ran `./bin/rake rails:update`, it wiped the contents of my `config/routes.rb` file, changed many of my settings in various config files (some of which were dangerous security settings to change), among a few other seemingly benign changes. While this is the expected behavior, I am pointing this out as not exactly a desirable method for updating a minor patch/hotfix for rails.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to change the version to 2.3.5 from 2.3.5 and then run

```
rake rails:update
```