# What does ~> mean in a gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the gem file for https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic they have:

```
 gem 'formtastic', '~> 2.0.0'
```

What does the ~> mean.
It actually gives me the error "Could not find gem 'formtastic (~> 2.0.0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources."

Comment: pessimistic version constraint or commonly referred to as a [twiddle-wakka](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic_version_constraint) via [RubyGems](http://guides.rubygems.org)

Comment: I think this is the better question. It's written in layman's terms, includes the word gem in the title, and (not surprisingly) has garnered more votes for both the question and the accepted answer than the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It's a confusing operand, but it limits versions to a subset of the possible versions. So `~> 2.0.0` means ">= 2.0.0 and < 2.1.0" in version numbers.

1.2.3 seems to be the latest version of Formtasic, that's why you're getting this error message.

Comment: so it means less than one plus the second digit?!?!  what is the logic behind that?!  what if you wanted it to be less than one plus the third digit. or less than one plus the first digit.  Also can you provide a source

Comment: no it isn't just for the third, it just depends on how many digits are given in the numeric version next to it. see the linked duplicate question

Comment: In my terraform it says GCP version must be ~> 3.46.0 so this means it can work with 3.0.0-3.46.0 ?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar `~> 3.46.0` means `>=3.46.0 && < 3.47.0`