# Rails version different by folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I'm just in my user folder and I do `rails -v` I get 5.0.2. However if I cd into the directory of my project I get 5.0.0.1.

Why is there a difference and how do I update my project to be the latest version of rails?

Comment: Check out `Gemfile` / `Gemfile.lock` files in your project. That's what specifies project version of rails. Also read up on Bundler.

Comment: Could also be a `.ruby-version` file coupled with RVM or rbenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler uses a `Gemfile.lock` to save the versions and names of gems. When this is checked into version control, it ensures that your set of gems are exactly same across all machines. This fosters stability in an ever changing world.

The `Gemfile.lock` is generated by bundler, and based on the syntax system of the `Gemfile` you can dictate version there.

If you'd like to update rails, you can run:

```
bundle update rails
```

You should be careful with updating gems. Make sure you have good test coverage and run your test suite after you update to ensure you haven't broken anything because of the update.

Here's a link to the [Gemfile.lock page](http://bundler.io/v1.14/guides/using_bundler_in_application.html#gemfilelock) of the bundler documentation, it covers a lot of these topics.

And, here's a link to the [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.14/guides/using_bundler_in_application.html#gemfilelock) docs.

Comment: I ended up just having to change in my gem file from 5.0.0.1 to 5.0.2 and then i ran bundle install, and then bundle update and it worked. I had already run bundle update rails but it didn't update that particular application for some reason.

Comment: Yes. This has to do with the syntax that you used when stating your rails gem in your Gemfile, e.g. `gem 'rails', '5.0.0.1'`. If you had used the `~>` syntax it would have updated without needing an explicit change, as the version change is not beyond 5.1. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101591/what-does-mean-in-a-gem-file