# Various difficulties creating Rails apps in different versions and installing Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree, gemfile

As per `rbenv -global` my ruby version is `2.3.3`

The versions of Rails I have:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (5.1.1, 5.0.0)
```

Initially, my goal was to create a Rails with Spree. Like usual I began with:

`rails new spree_app`

Following the [Spree README](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/README.md) I then added the following gems to my `gemfile`:

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
```

Then, when I ran `bundle install` I'm met with the following errors:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (= 5.1.1)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.1.1)

    spree (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      spree_frontend (= 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
        canonical-rails (~> 0.1.0) was resolved to 0.1.2, which depends on
          rails (< 5.1, >= 4.1)

    spree (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
        deface (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
          rails (>= 4.1)

    spree (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
        rails (~> 5.0.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Running `bundle update` as suggested yields me this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.1.1)

    spree (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
        rails (~> 5.0.0)
```

So it seems to me that Spree depends on Rails 5.0.0 and my 5.1.1 is causing problems. In light of this I changed `gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'` to `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'`, ran `bundle update` and `bundle install` and everything worked properly bundler-wise.

The issue is that this seems to have broken my rails app. Running, any `rails generate` commands or `rails s` gives me the following error:

```
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0055a1cd5a36f0> (NoMethodError)
```

For the life of me, I have no idea what is the matter here.

My final attempt was to try and generate a new Rails app in 5.0.0 with:

`rails _5.0.0_ new spree_app_2`

But for whatever reason, this seems to make no difference. The `gemfile` of this app still contains `gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'` and I am met with all the same errors that I got before hand.

So it seems that I either, don't know how to manage different versions of Rails, I'm not installing Spree correctly, or both. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Update: Partial Solution**

I still don't know how to generate a Rails app in any version other than `5.1.1`, and simply changing the version in the `gemfile` still doesn't work for me. It seems to me that some other changes are need.

I switched the version of rails in the `gemfile` from `5.1.1` to `5.0.3`. looked at the `/config/application.rb` files from Rails apps using `5.0.2` and found that they had a different setup.

Mine looked had this:

```
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.1
  end
end
```

And the rails app generated in `5.0.2` had like this:

```
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |generate|
      generate.assets false
    end
  end
end
```

So I swapped out what I had with that and it worked! I don't really know why it worked and I still don't know why I can just generate a `5.0.3` Rails app from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means a Spree expert, but from what it looks like, `5.1.1` is not compatible with Spree.

`spree (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      spree_frontend (= 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
        canonical-rails (~> 0.1.0) was resolved to 0.1.2, which depends on
          rails (< 5.1, >= 4.1)`

In your `Gemfile`, go ahead and put `gem 'rails', '5.0.3'` at the top (replacing any other `rails` gems), then `rm Gemfile.lock` followed by a `bundle`

Should do the trick.

Comment: Well, this gets rid of the issue with gem dependencies, but just as with what I did originally I get the same

`undefined method 'load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0055e0414ccdf0>` error whenever I attempt to run rails commands such as `rails s` or `rails generate`.

Comment: What about `gem install rails -v 5.0.3` and then `rails _5.0.3_ new application_name`?

Comment: reporting all-systems-go over here with 2.3.1; trying 2.3.3 real quick!

Comment: ... but first I get to install 2.3.3; joy!

Comment: Okay, I've done this and it doesn't seem to make a difference. My `gemfile` still contains `gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'` and running `bundle install` after adding the Spree gems gives me the same dependency complaints. 

Shouldn't I be seeing `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.3'` in my `gemfile` instead?

Comment: you forgot to delete Gemfile.lock first :) — Gemfile.lock will — you guessed it — lock the gem versions unless you're updating.

Comment: all systems go on 2.3.3 with Rails 5.0.3 and the listed spree gems :)

Comment: What do you mean by that? 

I ran `rails _5.0.3_ new application_name` and before touching anything the `gemfile` still contained `gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'`. I can delete `Gemfile.lock`, change `gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'` to `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.3'` and run `bundle update` and `bundle install` but I get that same error whenever I run rails commands. 

Is there some other `Gemfile.lock` that I should delete?

Comment: The reason you _might_ be experiencing this is because because you're using `~> 5.0.3` instead of just '5.0.3'; see this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101591/what-does-mean-in-a-gem-file

Comment: try uninstalling that Rails version completely, `gem uninstall rails -v 5.1.1`

Comment: I'm starting to suspect an operator error :) try this repo: https://github.com/joshmn/example — make sure you're using 2.3.3 and do a `bundle install` on it.

Comment: Yes, I was able to `bundle install` as well as run rails commands such as `rails s`. Related to what I explained in an edit to the OP, I believe the reason why I didn't get the error for this Rails app was because of what is in `/config/application.rb`.